# How to save ssh-keyscan result with the port to .ssh/known_hosts

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, known-hosts

When I run

```
ssh-keyscan -p NNN -t rsa GITHOST
```

it produces sting like

```
GITHOST ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAAAgQCZwBe6yneM2q2KEuQ3UV194hUcEcQ7b0xoYdKXKU6RrsxP2wup3uwC4q2SbPlW6XkjVtOIXY4c5aBaieMjNhIBFxGa2yUnTwZPFZiGMh/fwoZ2IsLsIE7XCj2q4eO1jmxvgWf7VAE7DVkGg5VTcRRoVOP5V15z9/saP5u4Tcwu1w==
```

And I add it to `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file.

But the git still asks me about key verification. Could be it b/c there is no port information stored in the `known_hosts` file ?

How can I create proper `known_hosts` in a script?

Comment: When you say you added it to known_hosts, what exactly did you add? How does the known_hosts file look?

Comment: what system are you using? Do you have `HashKnownHosts=yes`? If so, you will need to hash your hosts fin that file using `ssh-keygen -H` after that.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually not needed since current ssh-keyscan versions will add the port for you. Older versions did not do that. You could post-process the line with sed like this:

```
ssh-keyscan -p NNN -t rsa GITHOST | sed -E 's/^([^ \[]+) (.*)$/[\1]:NNN \2/'
```

The output of ssh-keyscan is piped into sed that will use a substitute regexp to transform the output of ssh-keyscan to include the port.

This will result in:

```
[GITHOST]:NNN ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAAAgQCZw....
```

**Update**: I refined the regexp above to play nice with ssh-keyscan output in already correct format.